# Special Chars not converting in to binary well in python

Tags: python, encryption, unicode, binary

I am working an a XOR encryption model in Python and thus far everything works great except for numbers, and punctuation.

Any number or punctuation will give you a invalid binary string however, any basic letters at least in the english alphabet work.

What am I doing wrong here? I have traced it down to this method:

```
def IMpassEnc(self,password):
    binaryList = ""
    for i in password:
        if i == " ":
            binaryList += "00100000"  #adding binary for space
        else:
            tmp = bin(int(binascii.hexlify(i),16)) #Binary Conversion
            newtemp = tmp.replace('b','')  
            binaryList += newtemp
    return binaryList
```

Comment: And what output *should* it give? What output do you get instead?

Comment: And using `binascii.hexlify()` then turning it into an integer again is rather round-about. Why not use `ord()` instead?

Comment: One sec let me send the out put.  And how would  u go about using ord in my case?

Comment: here is an example, say for the password I input the string "a!" the resulting binary is 011000010100001  however according to the charmaps of utf-8 it shouldb:0110000100110001 if you notice I am one bit off? the a is translated correctly but not the "!"

Comment: hmmm I can't speak to your general XOR encryption but for your specific problem which charmap table are you referring to?  the 'a' is hex=61 binary=1100001 and the '!' is hex=21 binary=100001.  Combined the result result should be '01100001'+'00100001'  The bin function returns a string bin(0)='0b00' and bin(1)='0b01' so you need to remove the first two characters from the result, not just the b.  Further since I assume you want 8 bits per character, you need to pad with '0' character until you have 8 bits.

Answer (score 2):

You need to generate binary representations that are 8 bits wide; `bin()` does *not* give you that.

The better way to produce these results is to use `format(value, '08b')`; this produces 8-character wide binary representations, padded with 0. Moreover; [`ord()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord) would be a much more direct way to get the integer codepoint for a given character:

```
>>> format(ord(' '), '08b')
'00100000'
>>> format(ord('a'), '08b')
'01100001'
>>> format(ord('!'), '08b')
'00100001'
```

or, put together using `''.join()`:

```
def IMpassEnc(self, password):
    return ''.join(format(ord(c), '08b') for c in password)
```